# No WIFI Card found

Tags: wireless-networking, device-manager, wifi-driver

My PC doesn't detect my wifi card, since I put it in sleep mode. I use a USB dongle and it works juste fine, but it's like I don't have a WIFI card anymore. It does not appear in the device manager as well. So how can I reinstall it?

Comment: What PC? What WiFi card? You seem to be using Windows but which version?

Comment: Asus N76V. Don't know what wifi card I have. I have Windows 8.1

Comment: If scanning for new hardware in Device Manager doesn't show it then it's probably hardware failure. I don't suppose you can test with a Linux LiveCD?

Comment: Did you try shutting the PC all the way down (not just putting it to sleep) and then powering it back on? Also, check if your laptop has a Wifi switch (either physical or through a function key.)

Comment: Well it's working again, I don't really know why. Thanks for the answers !